# Is it possible to loop when size of a tensor is not known?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I would like to read time series sequence saved in tfrecord format. Each time series has different length. What I want to achieve is to split a long tensor into batch of smaller tensors of requested length. It is very easy to do with numpy arrays and it would look like this:

```
length = 200
for begin in range(tensor_size-length):
     tensor_slice = tf.slice(my_tensor, begin, length)
     my_slices.append(tensor_slice)
```

In such function my problem is: how to get size of a tensor, so that using a loop could be possible?
Below is part of code where example is readed and decoded.

```
file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf_files, num_epochs=num_epochs)
        reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
        _, serialized_records = reader.read(file_queue)

        feature_map = {
            "speed":tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.float32, allow_missing=True),
            "battery":tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.float32, allow_missing=True)
        }

        features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_records, feature_map)
        speed = tf.cast(features['speed'], tf.float32)
        battery = tf.cast(features['battery'], tf.float32)
        speeds = []
        batteries = []

        #SPLIT TENSOR INTO SMALLER TENSORS
        features = tf.train.shuffle_batch([speeds, batteries],
                                           batch_size=batch_size,
                                           capacity=5000,
                                           num_threads=4,
                                           min_after_dequeue=1)

        return features
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot loop through a tensor like that in Python. You can use [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop), although it is generally avoided unless it is really the only way to achieve what you want, since it tends to be slow. In your case, you can get the result you want without looping, for example using [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather):

```
length = 200
features = ...
# Number of elements
n = tf.shape(features)[0]
# Index from zero to number of subtensors
split_idx = tf.range(n - length + 1)
# Index from zero to subtensor length
length_idx = tf.range(length)
# Indices for gather; each row advances one position, like a "rolling window"
gather_idx = split_idx[:, tf.newaxis] + length_idx
# Gather result
features_split = tf.gather(features, gather_idx)
```

Comment: Your solution is very clever, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem because the function: tf.trains.shuffle_batch( [tensors...] ..) requires that each tensor has defined shape. As a result of tf.gather we don't get a list of tensors, but "Gather" tensor, so it is impossible to use set_shape on each of them until we run the session.